# Debezium io with pulsar

Tags: debezium, apache-pulsar, pulsar

I want to understand how pulsar uses debezium io connect for CDC.
While creating the source using pulsar-admin source create, how can I pass broker url and authentication params or client. Similar to what we di when using localrun.

The cmd I run :
bin/pulsar-admin source localrun --sourceConfigFile debezium-mysql-source-config.yaml --client-auth-plugin  --client-auth-params   --broker-service-url

Now I want to replace this to create a connector which runs in cluster mode.

Answer (score 0):

Localrun is a special mode that simplifies debugging and it runs outside of normal cluster. It needs extra parameters to create the client for the local runtime.

In the cluster mode the connector will get the client from the Pulsar connectors runtime/through the function worker configuration. All you need to do is use "`bin/pulsar-admin source create ...`".

Comment: I tried running that, but source create authentication is not working properly. I am getting failure for client.

Comment: @ShreyaSinghal I suggest checking function worker configuration to make sure it has correct authentication settings (like broker).  Also it might be something version-specific or something that I am missing. I recommend asking in the pulsar mailing list or Slack and providing more details about the specific pulsar version you use and configuration.

Comment: I was using 2.7.2, version 2.9.1 gives auth for debezium clients